# Почему не видит значение из props в Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Подскажите, почему в setup при открытии страницы не видит props.value, если сделаю вывод в консоль просто props сonsole.log(props) то выводит содержимое, а props.value нет, пусто

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const { $axios } = useContext()

    const text = ref('')

    console.log(props)

    text.value = props.value
 }
})
```

Comment: пропс передаете точно ?)

Comment: да, в console.log(props) выдает value заполненный